# how to speech recognise from a file, System.ApplicationException 0xa SPXERR_INVALID_HEADER

Tags: c#, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to speech recognise on a wav file like this:

```
var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("mykey", "myregion");

using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(@"/Full/Path/To/File.wav")))
{
    recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        }
    };

    await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exception with an error code: 0xa (SPXERR_INVALID_HEADER)) ---> System.ApplicationException: Exception with an error code: 0xa (SPXERR_INVALID_HEADER)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpxExceptionThrower.ThrowIfFail(IntPtr hr)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Recognizer.FromConfig(GetRecognizerFromConfigDelegate fromConfig, SpeechConfig speechConfig, AudioConfig audioConfig)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognizer..ctor(SpeechConfig speechConfig, AudioConfig audioConfig)
   at mynamespace.Program.RecognizeSpeechAsync() in Program.cs:line 14
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at mynamespace.Program.Main() in Program.cs:line 46
```

line 14 is the

```
using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(@"/Full/Path/To/File.wav")))
```

line

How am I actually meant to use the speech service on a file? I got it working on  live mic input.

I just tried again with a file formatted differently (WAV file, 16 kHz sampling rate, mono) and I now get this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
Microsoft::CognitiveServices::Speech::Impl::ExceptionWithCallStack: Exception with
an error code: 0xd (SPXERR_ABORT)
```

Comment: I downloaded a wav file for the Internet and I was able to make it work with that, but I bump into the same trouble as you whenever I build the wav myself from a JS ui I've built.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. It turned out I had to *actually record in wav format* in the frontend javascript+html UI. The problem was that I was recording in audio/webm and posting the file to my backend. Although I did convert it successfully to wav in the backend and it did play properly, the Speech library didn't like that. Only when I made sure my frontend was wav did it work. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated yourself - it seems to be working with a standard WAV file ...

> > > I downloaded a wav file for the Internet and I was able to make it work with

It looks like your home-created WAV file isn't following the expected WAV format specification (WAV/PCM 16-bit, 16 kHz/8 kHz, single-channel audio)?

Wolfgang